# WCF RIA Services DomainContext

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Im building a page that has to receive data from a database and displaying in a datagrid.

I use WCF RIA Services for this effect. However when I create my DomainContext (based on an Entity Model) it returns no data whereas the database contains plenty of it.

When I do this on sql server

```
select * from resposta
```

this is the result:

```
id     data      hora   inquirido  resposta1    resposta2
1   01/04/2013  11:27   912345678   Sim            Não
2   01/04/2013  11:27   912345678   Sim            Não
```

And when i do the same thing with Entity Framework

```
_CurrentDomainContext = new CallbacksDomainContext();
contactoDataGrid.ItemsSource = _CurrentDomainContext.contactos;
EntityQuery<contacto> query = _CurrentDomainContext.FilterContactosQuery(ani, contacto, hora, data, horaUpper, dataUpper, espera, opcao, queueDestino, cliente);
LoadOperation<contacto> loadOp = _CurrentDomainContext.Load(query, SearchFinished, null);
```

I get an empty datagrid.

My ria DomainData source is this:

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="False" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my:resposta, CreateList=true}" Height="0"
                                  LoadedData="respostaDomainDataSource_LoadedData" x:Name="respostaDomainDataSource" 
                                  QueryName="GetResponsesQuery" Width="0">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext >
            <my:CallbacksDomainContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

I must be missing something... Cause i'm new to silverlight and WCF RIA so this is probably a newbie's mistake. But I really can't find the cause for this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing loading your DomainDataSource

```
DomainDataSource  AutoLoad="True"
```

Or in your code behind load it manually `respostaDomainDataSource.Load();`

Comment: I do it in the code like this: 
`_CurrentDomainContext = new CallbacksDomainContext();
                contactoDataGrid.ItemsSource =      _CurrentDomainContext.contactos;
                EntityQuery<contacto> query = _CurrentDomainContext.FilterContactosQuery(ani, contacto, hora, data, horaUpper, dataUpper, espera, opcao, queueDestino, cliente);
                LoadOperation<contacto> loadOp = _CurrentDomainContext.Load(query, SearchFinished, null);`

Comment: You should use DomainDataSource or manual loding as you filtered. DomainDataSource also has parameters for using such a parameter operation "FilterContactosQuery" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707363(v=vs.91).aspx